# How to use SSH-credentials?

Tags: jenkins-workflow

I try to convert a "standard" build to a workflow build. In the the original build we use the SSH-Agent plugin to access SSH-keys we need for deploying the artifacts in the builds shell-script. How can I do something like this in workflow? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Pending [JENKINS-28689](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28689) this would be tricky. You could save the private key as a *Secret Text* credentials item (pending [JENKINS-28399](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28399)), then use the `withCredentials` step (Credentials Binding plugin) to get a variable with a file location of a copy of the private key, and then authenticate with that.

Comment: Oh my... I see what I can make with this. Cheers, Shorty

Comment: Sadly it won't help me since the key has a password and this should not be visible.

Comment: Well, you could create a separate _Secret Text_ credentials item for the passphrase. At any rate, if you are storing the private key on the Jenkins master anyway, there is no compelling reason to make it be passphrase-protected; you do not get any additional security. You may as well decrypt it.